# Why does the .read() command do different things when the output is saved in a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminal

Here is what I'm doing in Terminal:

```
>>> file1 = open('file1.txt', 'r')
>>> file1.read()
    'Content 1'
>>> new_file1 = file1.read()
>>> print(new_file1)
```

Why is it that when I use a .read() command directly on file1 I get the content of the file, but when I try to *save* that output to a variable I get an empty string?

Comment: You read the file already.  There is no more to read when you try to read more.  Either reset the file pointer (`file1.seek(0)`), or close and re-open the file.

Comment: What `dsh` said. But of course, it's better if you can avoid reading the same file data more than once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`file`s are iterators, and reading a file exhausts the iterator.  In other words, the first `read()` uses it up.

To read the same file again you can either close then reopen the file, or move the file's internal pointer back to the beginning:  `file1.seek(0)`

**NB**  `file`s are special this way; most iterators cannot be reset.

Comment: Files are not *just* iterable. Most things that are iterable can be iterated multiple times (lists, for instance). But files *are iterators*. An iterator can usually only be used once. Files cheat a little bit on the iterator protocol by allowing you to `seek` back to the start after they've been exhausted. Most iterators don't let you do that.

Comment: @Blckknght: Thanks, fixed.